# Color a particular row in datatable depending on its cell content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, datatables

Friends,I have tried this a lot but i don't know where I am wrong.I am trying to color the cell of my datatable depending on its cell content,but nothing is happening. I have tried using fnrowcallback function ,Createdrow function ,but nothing is working out. When I change the comparison operator to "not equal to(!=)" it colors all the cells of my table.But when it is "equal to(==)" it does not work as required.I want to color the row if its 3rd column cell contains "A" or "Sat".Please check my code and let me know ,where did i go wrong.
Here is my code-

```
"fnRowCallback": function(nRow, aData, iDisplayIndex, iDisplayIndexFull) {
    if (aData[2] == "A")
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'pink');
    }
    else if (aData[2] == "Sat")
    {
        $('td', nRow).css('color', 'Orange');
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to debug your code. check what is the value of `aData[2]`.

Comment: If you put `console.log(aData[2])` just before `if ( aData[2] == "A" )`, what do you see?

Comment: you should not use else if in this case or you will need to have an else block at the end to execute the other conditions: 

if(condition) {//code} else if(condition) { //code} else { //code }

Comment: It gives me undefined @TewsonSeeoun

Comment: @pro even if i try that just for "A " it does not work

Comment: @payal_suthar Then the problem is not in this function, but in how you get the value of `aData`.

Comment: @tejashsoni111..it says undefined

Comment: since you know aData[2] is undefined, next console.log(aData), if that is undefined as well, you will need to find out why aData is undefined

Comment: that is what i want to know..I have A in my database and this table is retrieving values from my database and displaying them.Then why is it telling me that it is undefined @Ji_in_coding

Comment: that is what i want to know..I have A in my database and this table is retrieving values from my database and displaying them.Then why is it telling me that it is undefined@TewsonSeeoun

Comment: why do you have color instead of background-color?  $('td', nRow).css('color', 'Orange'); ? It should be $('td', nRow).css('background-color', 'Orange');

Comment: I don't mind giving them any css property...Thats not my concern ..@pro

Comment: When i write console.log(aData); it gives me all the values @Ji_in_coding

Comment: It is not giving undefined then @Ji_in_coding

Comment: DT_RowId
:
"row_5"
date
:
"Tue, 11 Oct "
deepa
:
"A"
dhanraj
:
"A"
dilip
:
"A"
ishwar
:
"A"
lalit
:
"A"
neetu
:
""
rajesh
:
"A"
ramesh
:
"A" it gives me this @Ji_in_coding

Comment: @payal_suthar You are trying to access the index `2` in `aData`, however it seems like your `aData` is an object. You have to access whichever property you expect to be `A` with the property name, for example, `aData.deepa` or `aData.dhanraj` instead of `aData[2]`.

Comment: It says ...aData[dhanraj] is not defined@TewsonSeeoun

Comment: @payal_suthar I made typos. Please see my updated comment.

Comment: Ohk ..finally got it..It should be `aData['dhanraj']` instead of `aData[dhanraj]`...thank you @TewsonSeeoun..

Comment: @TewsonSeeoun..can u please let me know how can i color the entire row if a cell contains that particular word along with other words

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this works for you if you're willing to use jQuery:

```js
$('td:contains("three")').css('background', 'red');
$('td:contains("two")').css('background', 'yellow');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
<tr><td>one</td><td>two</td></tr>
<tr><td>three</td><td>four</td></tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the dataype of aData. It its an object then accessing it via object notation should not give you undefined. My guess is it might be a json string???